# Can anyone explain the output step by step?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, apply

I'm working on the Kaggle's Titanic case, walking through the following website:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/09/data-munging-python-using-pandas-baby-steps-python/

I'm confused by how the function "def fage[x]" turns "pivot table" into "Series" as the final output. I'm new to machine learning and wish to work harder on it. Many thanks!

```
table = df.pivot_table(values='Age', index=['New_Salutation'], columns=['Pclass', 'Sex'], aggfunc=np.median)

# Define function to return value of this pivot_table

def fage(x):
    return table[x['Pclass']][x['Sex']][x['New_Salutation']]

# Replace missing values

df['Age'].fillna(df[df['Age'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1), inplace=True)
```

Output is:
 A single "Series" with values

Comment: That being said, if you can add some sample data so that we can run that code snippet successfully from start to finish, then perhaps someone will answer your question. See how to create a [mcve]. As it stands right now, it's a lot of work to reproduce and in general broad questions like "what does this do" aren't the best Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @ALollz I agree the chain selection looks terrible but I would have deifned the table outside as well since functions to be used as row-wise apply can't have more parameters than one. Is that true or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an IDE that will let you step through the program? I use [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) myself. I hope this helps, as I don't know anything about machine learning this is the best I can do.